# Making classfactory that derive from dataclass objects informed by types in python

Tags: python, python-typing, metaclass, python-dataclasses

When using `dataclasses.dataclass` the type information informs how parameters are parsed. I would like to take a defined `dataclass` and produce a class that changes all the attribute type declarations from `X` to `Optional[List[X]]`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import DataClassJsonMixin
from datetime import datetime

@dataclass
class SrcClass(DataClassJsonMixin):
    number: int
    name: str
    at: datetime

SrcClassLister = make_lister(SrcClass)
```

I want the function `make_lister` to produce a class similar to the class defined below.

```py
@dataclass
class SrcClassLister(DataClassJsonMixin):
    numbers: Optional[List[int]]
    names: Optional[List[str]]
    ats: Optional[List[datetime]]
```

I am unsure how type information is captured for parsing by the `dataclass`.

My reason for doing this is I have a high variety of dataclass definitions and I would like to automatically make a spec for filtering. This spec would take a list of values that are acceptable for a pass-filter.

Comment: regardless of the answers provided, I don't think you are taking a good approach for _any_ problem there: if the "number" "name" and "at" attributes are fro a given instance of an object, and you have several of these objects, you should deal with lists of these objects, not create a class that holds independent lists of the attributes and having to handle the indexes manually. If you are better off with a table, then yes, use Pandas, a column for each of the attributes - and each row of the Pandas dataframe will refer to one of your objects.

Comment: I am aware of that, I needed to know how to start this in order to make a types informed solution. I am still going to use this approach, and appreciate that you have a different opinion on the matter.

Comment: A primary reason that I have for this approach is that I need to be able to specify filter criteria over json. I am however inspecting the `type` of each input field, to determine the naming convention and filter rule for each derived filter. This will include bounds filters for ordinal fields, list for `Enum` categorical fields, and union intersection rules for polygon fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine something like

```
import dataclasses
import typing
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import DataClassJsonMixin
from datetime import datetime


@dataclass
class SrcClass(DataClassJsonMixin):
    number: int
    name: str
    at: datetime
    purpose: int = 42


def pluralize(name):
    # TODO: improve this if you will
    return name + "s"


def make_lister(src_cls):
    fields = [
        (pluralize(field.name), typing.Optional[typing.List[field.type]], dataclasses.field(default=None))
        for field in dataclasses.fields(src_cls)
    ]
    name = f"{src_cls.__name__}Lister"
    return dataclasses.make_dataclass(name, fields, bases=(DataClassJsonMixin,))


SrcClassLister = make_lister(SrcClass)

scl = SrcClassLister(numbers=[1, 2])
print(scl)
print(scl.to_json())
```

works for you - this prints out

```
SrcClassLister(numbers=[1, 2], names=None, ats=None, purposes=None)
{"numbers": [1, 2], "names": null, "ats": null, "purposes": null}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively straightforward:

```py
from dataclasses import make_dataclass

def make_lister(cls)
    return make_dataclass(
        cls.__name__ + "Filter", # Assuming you want to name
                                 # the new class like that
        [(key, Optional[List[value]]) for key, value in cls.__annotations__.items()],
    )
```

Note that there are a few quirks:

1. If you want to use this function as a decorator instead, maybe you shouldn't change the name of the dataclass. Dataclasses must know their name, it's like that.
2. This will ditch any additional information about fields (like their default constructor or stuff like that). If you want that, you should probably go through the `Field` interface instead; it's just that, since you didn't mention how you wanted to handle that, I didn't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a decorator, or by doing this:

```
from typing import List, Optional
from dataclasses_json import DataClassJsonMixin
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime


@dataclass
class SrcClass(DataClassJsonMixin):
    number: int
    name: str
    at: datetime


def make_lister(some_class):

    modified_class = type('Lister', (some_class,), {})
    new_annotations = {}

    for attr, type_ in modified_class.__annotations__.items():
        new_annotations[attr + 's'] = Optional[List[type_]]

    modified_class.__annotations__ = new_annotations

    return modified_class

SrcClassLister = make_lister(SrcClass)

print(SrcClassLister.__annotations__)
```

Printing the expected output.